# Change details of an mp3 using either java or C++

Tags: java, c++, mp3

I am trying to cleanup my mp3 collection and I have a bunch of songs that have the artist at the beginning of the song or numbers so I wanted to know if there is a way take the number from the filename and put it into the details (track number) of the file.  I already know how to read files from folders I am just not sure how to change the details of a file if possible.

Comment: You need to modify the file's metadata; APIs exist for this, or you can parse the file manually (if you read the file as a string and print it, you can find your artist data and what not fairly easily).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using [Mp3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) it's a very nice application that actually has tools for analyzing file names and putting the details in to the tags.